# HAProxy no such ACL : 'ssl_fc'

Tags: proxy, haproxy

I'm using HAProxy in Docker:

```
FROM haproxy:1.8.9
```

My configurations looks like this:

```
global
    maxconn 256
    log 127.0.0.1 local0
    nbproc 1

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    log-format frontend:%f/%H/%fi:%fp\ client:%ci:%cp\ GMT:%T\ body:%[capture.req.hdr(0)]\ request:%r
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

    timeout queue 60000ms
    timeout http-request 15000ms
    timeout http-keep-alive 15000ms
    option redispatch
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    #    option  httplog
    #    option  dontlognull

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /secrets/server.pem
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    mode http
    default_backend splunk_servers
```

During startup I'm getting:

```
parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:26] : error detected in frontend 'http-in' while parsing redirect rule : error in condition: no such ACL : 'ssl_fc'
```

Do you know why?

According to HAProxy [docs](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.3.4-ssl_fc) this ACL should be available.

When I run it with `-vv` option the output looks like this:

```
Build options :
       TARGET  = linux2628
       CPU     = generic
       CC      = gcc
       CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fwrapv -fno-strict-overflow -Wno-null-dereference -Wno-unused-label
       OPTIONS = USE_ZLIB=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_LUA=1 USE_PCRE=1

     Default settings :
       maxconn = 2000, bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200

     Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
     Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
     OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
     OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
     OpenSSL library supports : TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
     Built with Lua version : Lua 5.3.3
     Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND
     Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
     Built with multi-threading support.
     Built with PCRE version : 8.39 2016-06-14
     Running on PCRE version : 8.39 2016-06-14
     PCRE library supports JIT : no (USE_PCRE_JIT not set)
     Built with zlib version : 1.2.8
     Running on zlib version : 1.2.8
     Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity"), deflate("deflate"), raw-deflate("deflate"), gzip("gzip")
     Built with network namespace support.
```

It looks like HAProxy is built with SSL, so what's wrong?

Comment: `ssl_fc` is a fetch, not an ACL... but HAProxy would probably assume it's intended to be an ACL if you compiled without TLS support. Check `haproxy -vv`?

Comment: I have edited my question. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I tried to use this Dockerfile: https://github.com/haproxytech/haproxy-docker-ubuntu/blob/master/Dockerfile-1.8 and still the same error.